# Symmetrize Along Custom Transform Orientation

Tags: transforms, customization

Can one symmetrize (eg. *-X to +X* after making a selection in *Edit* mode and pressing *W* - pressing *Symmetrize*) along a custom transform orientation? I have selected my orientation *Custom*, but when I symmetrize it is done according to global transform orientation.

Comment: How are you symmetrizing it?

Comment: I don't *believe* you can since the custom transform is for simple manipulation (TRS).  However, you can always align your object with the axis you want to symmetrize along and then after symmetrizing, rotate it back.

Comment: Interactive mirror (Ctrl+M) will work based on transform orientations, custom ones as well. But it mirrors only, so one needs to duplicate data before mirroring if original is required untouched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now at least, it seems that the ***Symmetrize*** algorithm is based on the object's ***Local Axis*** and the ***Object Origin*** regardless of the ***Orientation*** or the ***Pivot*** selection.

[image]

Comment: This is the way I approached this, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake - No problem at all.  Glad it helped you

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me. I guess it's the matter of the proper placing of the object's origin point.
[image]

You may also try mirroring with *Empty*. In *Edit Mode* select the face you want to add a custom transformation to, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to set it. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num 7</kbd> to allign the face to view. Enter *Object Mode*, add an *Empty* and check the *Align to View* checkbox. Add a *Mirror Modifier* and set the *Empty* as a mirror object's target. Now translate the *Empty* or the object along your custom transformation.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess rotation isn't applied to the cube in the first gif? Mirror or Symmetrize will work based on global axes so once rotation is applied one should hack it somehow, e.g. with the second gif

Comment: Mirroring doesn't do the same thing as symmetrizing.  Can you show an example of the symmetrize function working with a custom orientation?

Comment: @bertmoog You're right. Seems I misunderstood the question. Though my solution may be handy if you delete one half of the mesh and then use it (as the Mr Zak 's one with *Ctrl+M*).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! YOU SAVE ME A TON OF TIME. add empty and align to view will help mirror over the custom orientation